# struct size is different from typedef version?

Tags: c++, struct

I have the following struct declaration and typedef in my code:

```
struct blockHeaderStruct {
    bool allocated;
    unsigned int length;
};
typedef struct blockHeaderStruct blockHeader;
```

When I do `sizeof(blockheader)`, I get the value of 4 bytes back, but when I do `sizeof(struct blockHeaderStruct)`, I get 8 bytes.

Why is this happening? Why am I not getting 5 back instead?

Comment: Are you sure you're not taking the `sizeof` a pointer?

Comment: Also, due to padding for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_alignment, the expected value is 8, not 5.

Comment: What platform?  Which compiler?

Comment: `sizeof(blockheaderStruct)` will not even compile. Provide real `sizeof` expressions that you are trying to compare.

Comment: sizeof(blockHeaderStruct) will compile if this is C++ instead of C.

Comment: @Windows programmer: Yes, but the question is tagged C, not C++. So, once again, this will not even compile.

Comment: @AndreyT: Although, `bool` is not a standard C type, and given that the OP seems adamant his code compiles, chances are this question should be tagged `c++`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: `bool` is only usable if one includes `<stdbool.h>`. The *real* type is `_Bool`.

Comment: @dreamlax: Yes, but that's beside the point. `bool` in a code snippet is no longer a contradiction with a C tag.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Yeah you're right. Usually when I see `bool` I assume C++; probably because I always considered it "one of the differences" between C and C++.

Comment: Is there any significance to the fact that you define 'blockHeader' with a capital H and take the `sizeof(blockheader)` with lower case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the definition of your struct, you have 1 byte value followed by 4 byte Integer. This integer needs to be allocated on 4 byte boundary, which will force compiler to insert a 3 byte padding after your 1 byte bool. Which makes the size of struct to 8 byte. To avoid this you can change order of elements in the struct.

Also for two sizeof calls returning different values, are you sure you do not have a typo here and you are not taking size of pointer or different type or some integer variable.

Comment: Changing the order of elements will sometimes reduce padding, but not in this case.

Comment: You can also add the "packed" compiler flag so that it always returns 5 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you cannot do `sizeof(blockHeaderStruct)`. That simply will not compile. What you can do is `sizeof(struct blockHeaderStruct)`, which could indeed give you 8 bytes as result.

Secondly, getting a different result from `sizeof(blockheader)` is highly unlikely. Judging by your reference to `sizeof(blockHeaderStruct)` (which, again, will not even compile) your description of the problem is inaccurate. Take a closer look at what is it you are really doing. Most likely, you are taking a `sizeof` of a pointer type (which gives you 4), not a struct type.

In any case, try posting real code.

Comment: sizeof(blockHeaderStruct) compiled just fine for me in g++ 4.2 (note this is tagged C++ not C).

Comment: @Mark B: This was tagged C originally, and retagged C++ only 7 hours ago. My answer was posted 18 hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that you are actually looking at the size of a pointer, not the `struct`, on a 32-bit system.

However, `int` may be 2 bytes (16 bits). In that case, the expected size of the structure is 4:

- 2 bytes for the `int`
- 1 byte for the `bool`
- round up to the next multiple of 2, because the size of the struct is usually rounded to a multiple of the size of its largest primitive member.

Nothing could explain `sizeof(blockHeaderStruct) != sizeof(struct blockHeader)`, though, given that `typedef`. That is completely impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Struct allocation normally occurs on a 4 byte boundary. That is the compiler will pad data types within a struct up to the 4 byte boundary before starting with the next data type. Given that this is c++ (bool is a sizeof 1) and not c (bool needs to be #define as something)

```
    struct blockHeaderStruct {
       bool allocated;         // 1 byte followed by 3 pad bytes
       unsigned int length;    // 4 bytes
    };
    typedef struct blockHeaderStruct blockHeader;
    typedef struct blockHeaderStruct *blockHeaderPtr;
```

A sizeof operation would result:

```
sizeof(blockHeader) == 8
sizeof(struct blockHeader) == 8
sizeof(blockHeaderPtr) == 4
```

> (Note: The last entry will be 8 for a
>   64 bit compiler. )

There should be no difference in sizes between the first two lines of code. A typedef merely assigns an alias to an existing type. The third is taking the sizeof a pointer which is 4 bytes in a 32 bit machine and 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine.

---

To fix this, simply apply the #pragma pack directive before a structure is defined. This forces the compiler to pack on the specified boundary. Usually set as 1,2,or 4 (although 4 is normally the default and doesn't need to be set).

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(1)
struct blockHeaderStruct {
    bool allocated;
    unsigned int length;
};
typedef struct blockHeaderStruct blockHeader;

int main()
{
    printf("sizeof(blockHeader) == %li\n", sizeof(blockHeader));
    printf("sizeof(struct blockHeader) == %li\n", sizeof(struct blockHeaderStruct));

    return 0;
}
```

> Compiled with g++ (Ubuntu
>   4.4.1-4ubuntu9) 4.4.1

Results in:

```
sizeof(blockHeader) == 5  
sizeof(structblockHeader) == 5
```

You don't normally need this directive. Just remember to pack your structs efficiently. Group smaller data types together. Do not alternate < 4 byte datatypes and 4 byte data types as your structs will be mostly unused space.  This can cause unnecessary bandwidth for network related applications.

Answer (score 0):

> I actually copied that snippet direct
>   from my source file.

OK.

> When I do sizeof(blockheader), I get
>   the value of 4 bytes back

It looks like blockheader is typedef'ed somewhere and its type occupies 4 bytes or its type requires 4 byte alignment.

If you try sizeof(blockHeader) you'll get your type.

> when I do sizeof(blockHeaderStruct), I
>   get 8 bytes.

The reason why alignment matters is that if you need an array of blockHeaders then you can compute how much memory you need.  Or if you have an array and need to compute how much memory to copy, you can compute it.

If you want to align all struct members to addresses that are multiples of 1 instead of 4 or instead of your compiler's defaults, your compiler might offer a #pragma to do it.  Then you'll save memory but accesses might be slower in order to access unaligned data.

Comment: and the name of that pragma on almost all compilers is `#pragma align`.

Answer (score -1):

Some compilers will optimize to always allocate data by powers of 2 (4 stays 4, but 5 is rounded up to 8).

Comment: Wouldn't that get rid of the boolean value though?

Comment: Typically variables are aligned by their own individual size.

Comment: I don't know the sizes of each data type on your platform, but if you were expecting 5 and got 8, this is why.

Comment: @Potatoswatter
Not true for 64bit variables on x86-32 which are generally 4 byte aligned.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#x86_and_x86-64